# How to use orderby for date in miliseconds

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get all recoders orderd by decending date

I tried following approach
`MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE` contains date strings  in miliseconds (like 1411982657593). However,I still recieve record orderd by their creation instead of selected date. What should i fix?

```
public ArrayList<MyCelebration> getAllComments() {
        ArrayList<MyCelebration> myCelebrations = new ArrayList<MyCelebration>();
        String orderBy = "datetime("+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + ") DESC";
        Cursor cursor = database.query(
                MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CELEBRATION, allColumns, null, null, null, null, orderBy
        );

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            MyCelebration myCelebration = cursorToComment(cursor);
            myCelebrations.add(myCelebration);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return myCelebrations;
    }
```

Comment: `String orderBy = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC";` ??

Comment: "datetime()" is not required. Order By will give you rows from the highest COLUMN_DATE to the lowest.

Comment: I think `orderBy = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC";` should be enough

Comment: @Selvin, as comments are indentical and they are solve my problem, post you your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by comments, to order raws by dates:

```
String orderBy = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC";
```